# How do I convert Wifi.localIP() to String and store it to external variable

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to store the ip address into an extern string. My ip address value is in .cpp but then I want to store it in my .h file. I am storing it as string since I want to make it as a link. (http:// "ip address" /)

My .h file

```
extern std::string ipadd1 = "";
```

My .cpp file

```
if (connectWifi("", "") == WL_CONNECTED)   {
    DEBUG_WM(F("IP Address:"));
    DEBUG_WM(WiFi.localIP());
ipadd1 = String(WiFi.localIP());
    //connected
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: how do you convert it?

Comment: You should mark `WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str();` as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 5 min search give me [the WiFi.localIp() function description](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiLocalIP), from there I knew it returned `IPAddress` object. Following to [forum.arduino.cc Topic: How to manipulate IPAddress variables / convert to string](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=228884.0) you can use following function to convert it to string:

```
// author apicquot from https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=228884.0
String IpAddress2String(const IPAddress& ipAddress)
{
    return String(ipAddress[0]) + String(".") +
           String(ipAddress[1]) + String(".") +
           String(ipAddress[2]) + String(".") +
           String(ipAddress[3]);
}
```

`IPAddress` may be handled just as an array of 4 `int`s.

Comment: How to assign to variable tho ?

Answer (score 24):

Convert the `IPAddress` to a `String`, then get the `const char *` and convert that to an `std::string`.

```
ipadd1 = WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str();
```

Comment: Does `ipadd1 = std::string(WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str())` work? Note there is a difference between `std::string` and `String`.

Comment: @KamilCuk can you update your answer above to reflect this? Might be worth providing both examples, one for char* and one for std::string.

Answer (score 5):

If we want to write `Wifi.localIP()` in `oled(SSD1306)` or serial just write `WiFi.localIP().toString()`. Like this:

```
Serial.print("Connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP().toString());

  display.clear();
  display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);
  display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_10);
  display.drawString(0, 0, " WiFi is Connected." );
  
  display.drawString(0, 10, " IP address: "  + WiFi.localIP().toString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with Heltec... other answers just not working for me. I have used this:

```
IPAddress ipa = WiFi.localIP();
uint8_t IP_array[4]= {ipa[0],ipa[1],ipa[2],ipa[3]};
String strIP=
    String(IP_array[0])+"."+
    String(IP_array[1])+"."+
    String(IP_array[2])+"."+
    String(IP_array[3]);
```